# Запуск приложения или файла

Tags: c, exec

есть такой кусок кода, не могу понять почему не хочет работать.

Команда для запуска куска кода: exec text.txt

Но компилятор пишет: **ERROR: exec failed**

Пробовал другие команды из группы exec, результат тот же

```
else if(strcmp(args[0], "exec") == 0) {
            pid_t  pid;
            int    status;

            if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
                printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else if (pid == 0) {
                if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0) {
                    printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            else {
                while (wait(&status) != pid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Для начала было б  полезным выводить код ошибки, который записывается в `errno`. А потом подумать, какой вы ожидаете результат от запуска **текстового** файла

Comment: напишите подробнее , в чём ошибка так : `int en = error ; printf("e = %s\n",strerror(en));`

Answer (score 0):

Перед вызовом *execvp(args[0], args)* распечатайте значение *args[0]* и убедитесь в том, что:

1. Там содержится имя  файла, а не какой-то мусор;
2. Этот файл имеет режим **исполнимый**;
3. Если его имя содержит символ '/', то оно должно быть **абсолютным** путём;
4. Если слэша нет, то этот файл должен располагаться где-то по пути из переменной PATH;
5. Если предполагается, что исполнимый файл расположен в текущей директории, то его имя **обязательно** должно начинаться с сисмволов './'
6. Этот файл сам по себе - запускается нормально.